# A question regarding converse errors.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Consider the following argument form -
$$ \text{If}\ p\ \text{then}\ q$$
$$p$$
$$\therefore q$$
I can see why this argument form is valid by constructing a truth table. But I'm not sure whether I understand it intuitively. If I were to explain why this argument form is correct without using a truth table, my explanation would be as follows -

*$\text{If}\ p\ \text{then}\ q$ means that if $p$ is true, then $q$ is certainly true too. So if $p$ is true (as given by the minor premise), by the definition of a conditional statement, $q$ is true too.*

Additionally, If I were to explain why the following argument form is incorrect without using a truth table -
$$ \text{If}\ p\ \text{then}\ q$$
$$q$$
$$\therefore p$$
then my explanation would be as follows -

*$q$ therefore $p$ means $q \rightarrow p$. This is not the same as $ \text{If}\ p\ \text{then}\ q$, which is why the above argument form is invalid.*

As you can probably tell, I'm viewing the major premise and conclusion as "the major premise implies the conclusion."

$\large\textbf{Questions}$

Do my justifications as to why modulus ponens arguments are correct and why converse error arguments are incorrect make sense?

Comment: Your reasoning, " This is not the same as If p then q, which is why the above argument form is invalid." is not good reasoning. The fact that "they are not the same" doesn't mean the above argument form is invalid. One way to show that $q\rightarrow p$ and $p$ does not imply $q$, would be to present a counter-example.

Comment: If you do not want to use truth table, you have to find some "real life" conterexample: If it rains, then it is cloudy. It is cloudy. Therefore, it rains. The second premise can be true but the conclusion false.

Comment: The detachment rule (modus ponens) would seem to be one the defining features of the implication operator. Did you have another definition in mind? Maybe $A \to B~\equiv~ \neg (A\land \neg B)$?

Answer (score 1):

Your first explanation is fine.

The explanation for why the second pattern of reasoning (which is typically referred to as the Fallacy of Affirming the COnsequent)  is really not. Just because some argument does not follow the same pattern as Modus Ponens does not mean that it is not valid.

In effect, you are making the following argument:

$$\text{If an argument follows a Modus Ponens pattern, then it is valid}$$

$$\text{Here is an argument pattern does not follow a Modus Ponens pattern}$$

$$\text{Therefore, here is an argument pattern that is not valid}$$

The abstract form of your argument therefore is:

$$ \text{If}\ p\ \text{then}\ q$$
$$\text{not } p$$
$$\therefore \text{not } q$$

This pattern is often referred to as the Fallacy of Denying the Antecedent, and (as the name says) it is not valid!

Why?

Well, as other commenters have already pointed out, a good way to show that an argument is invalid (without using a truth-table) is to come up with a counterexample:  some scenario where the premises are true but the conclusion is false. So, let me do that for the above argument.

First, consider yet another argument pattern called Modus Tollens:

$$ \text{If}\ p\ \text{then}\ q$$
$$\text{not } q$$
$$\therefore \text{not } p$$

Note that the pattern of this argument is *not* the Modus Ponens. So, by your argument, it is supposed to be invalid. But Modus Tollens is valid: Without using  truth-table, I can explain that by pointing out that if $q$ is true whenever $p$ is true, then if we know that $q$ is not true, then $p$ cannot be the case, because if $p[$ were the case, we would have $q$, which we don't.

OK, so Modus Tollens is a counterexample to your earlier argument pattern: we *do* have that *if* Modus Tollens would be of the form Modus Ponens, then it would be valid. We also have that Moduss Tollens does not follow the Modus Ponens pattern. But, we do *not* have that Modus Tollens is not valid.

Finally, note that we can also point to Modus Tollens as a counterexample to the Affirming the Consequent pattern of argument. Again, we can say that *if* Modus Tollens would be of the form Modus Ponens, then it would be valid. And we also have that Modus Tollens is valid. But we don't have that Modus Tollens follow the Modus Ponens pattern.

Comment: Thank you! Can you also please explain why converse error arguments are incorrect without using a truth table?

Comment: @VedantRana  What do you mean by 'converse error arguments'?

Comment: Arguments in the following form - 
$$ p \rightarrow q$$
$$ \sim p $$
$$\therefore \ \sim q$$
The textbook I'm using calls this a converse error. Can you explain why these are invalid without using a truth table? I'm looking for an intuitive explanation.

Comment: @VedantRana I tried to do exactly that in my post ... but I am afraid I tried to be too cute and used your very own argument!  That is, the second explanation you made in your post has this very form (see begining of my post) and I explain in my post thatthat is not a good argument pattern, because you could have used that same logic to argue that Modus Tollens is not valid ... but Modus Tollens *is* valid. So, that right there is a counterexample.

Comment: @VedantRana But like I said, that's a little too 'meta'. Let me do a much simpler one:  'If it's my birthday, then I am happy. It is not my birthday. Therefore, I am not happy.'.  Good argument?  No!  I can be happy for many reasons other than it being my birthday (maybe I won the lottery). So, just because it's not my birthday doesn't mean I am not happy. So that's a very simple counterexample to the argument.